# Netflix crashes my Ubuntu 14.04 + Chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, crash, netflix

Ubuntu 14.04 + Chrome (latest version) worked fine with Netflix until they changed the interface around May 2015.

Now the site loads, titles + images are displayed, but as soon as I move the mouse (don't get the chance to click) on a title (movie poster) it takes about 5 seconds for screen to go black and the only solution is to reload.

Only happens with Netflix...

System is up-to-date.

It seems like a kernel crash, but I'm not sure. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I did reinstall completely the machine, same distro Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE this time (previous was Unity).

The surprise was that this time the page was loading correctly (even that bubble effect when you have the mouse over a movie poster), but after a few seconds the mouse symbol was freezing. I said mouse symbol, because I could see that the mouse was actually moving (I could still see the highlight while going over a button in XFCE).

I was not really happy with this so I did some more troubleshooting.

**The solution**, or better said the workaround for me was to **disable in Google Chrome** the "***Use hardware acceleration when available***" option from Settings. I don't know why this is messing up with the Netflix interface.

After I disabled this option everything was working fine.

I have an old HP DC7900 which still does the job. Maybe there is some incompatibility with the hardware / kernel version / google chrome...

I hope this will help or at least give you a clue.

Comment: The question is, why? Is it because of a memory issue? I have a similar  issue but it occurs when someone has been watching netflix for an extended period. The video freezes and the audio continues.

Comment: I haven't notice any memory usage issue, but it can be something which is not visible...